# MySQL optimize slow performing query when using not equals operator

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I am using MySQL 5.7 and have the following query it takes over 8 sec to execute which is too slow.

```
explain select distinct `jobs`.*
      , CASE WHEN jobs.alt_company_name IS NOT NULL OR job_files.path IS NOT NULL 
          THEN job_files.path 
          ELSE company_files.path 
        END AS logo_path
      , `applications`.`created_at` as `application_date` 
from `jobs` 
inner join `job_status` on `job_status`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
inner join `recruiters` on `recruiters`.`id` = `jobs`.`recruiter_id`
inner join `companies` on `companies`.`id` = `recruiters`.`company_id` 
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `jobs`.`location_id` 
inner join `location_name` on `location_name`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
inner join `job_language` on `job_language`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
inner join `languages` on `languages`.`id` = `job_language`.`language_id` 
inner join `job_industry` on `job_industry`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join `job_salary` on `job_salary`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join (SELECT fileable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
            FROM files WHERE file_type = "JobLogo" AND fileable_type = "App\\Job"
            GROUP BY fileable_id) AS subquery_one on `subquery_one`.`fileable_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join `files` as `job_files` on `job_files`.`fileable_id` = `subquery_one`.`fileable_id` and `job_files`.`created_at` = `subquery_one`.`min_created_at` 
left join (SELECT fileable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
            FROM files WHERE file_type = "CompanyLogo" AND fileable_type = "App\\Company"
            GROUP BY fileable_id) AS subquery_two on `subquery_two`.`fileable_id` = `companies`.`id` 
left join `files` as `company_files` on `company_files`.`fileable_id` = `subquery_two`.`fileable_id` and `company_files`.`created_at` = `subquery_two`.`min_created_at` 
left join `job_shortlist` on `job_shortlist`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` and `job_shortlist`.`jobseeker_id` is NULL 
left join `applications` on `applications`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` and `applications`.`jobseeker_id` is NULL 
where (`languages`.`id` in ('1') or `languages`.`parent_id` in ('1')) 
and `job_industry`.`industry_id` in ('1', '5','6') 
and `jobs`.`contract_type_id` in ('3') 
and `jobs`.`contract_hour_id` in ('1') 
and `jobs`.`id` <> 6 
and `applications`.`id` is NULL 
and `jobs`.`start_at` <= '2020-03-13 15:06:29' 
and `jobs`.`end_at` >= '2020-03-13 15:06:29' 
and `jobs`.`status_id` = 4 
order by jobs.start_at desc, jobs.id desc limit 4
```

Explain Results:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                 | key                                     | key_len | ref                                 | rows | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jobs          | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,jobs_status_id_foreign,jobs_recruiter_id_foreign,jobs_contract_type_id_foreign,jobs_contract_hour_id_foreign,jobs_location_id_foreign | jobs_status_id_foreign                  | 8       | NULL                                |    6 |    16.67 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_language  | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,job_language_language_id_foreign                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | languages     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,languages_parent_id_index                                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.job_language.language_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_industry  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,job_industry_industry_id_foreign                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                                 | 8       | testjobsdb.jobs.id,const            |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jobs          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,jobs_status_id_foreign                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_salary    | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | recruiters    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,recruiters_company_id_foreign                                                                                                         | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.recruiter_id        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | companies     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.recruiters.company_id    |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | status_types  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.status_id           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | locations     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.location_id         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t0            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.location_id         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                                                                                                                   | <auto_key1>                             | 5       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_files     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>    | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                                                                                                                   | <auto_key1>                             | 5       | testjobsdb.recruiters.company_id    |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | company_files | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_shortlist | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,job_shortlist_job_id_unique                                                                                                           | PRIMARY                                 | 8       | const,testjobsdb.jobs.id            |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | applications  | NULL       | eq_ref | applications_job_id_jobseeker_id_unique,applications_jobseeker_id_foreign                                                                     | applications_job_id_jobseeker_id_unique | 8       | testjobsdb.jobs.id,const            |    1 |    25.00 | Using where; Not exists                                             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t4            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin4_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin4_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin4,const          |    3 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t3            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin3_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin3_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin3,const          |    4 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t2            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin2_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin2_feature_code_index     | 366     | testjobsdb.t0.admin2,const          |   12 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin1_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin1_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin1,const          |   70 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                                               |
|  3 | DERIVED     | files         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |     1.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | files         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |     1.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
23 rows in set, 1 warning (8.30 sec)
```

If I remove the where condition `and jobs.id <> 6` or remove the subquery left joins the query executes in under 0.11 sec

```
explain select distinct `jobs`.*
      , CASE WHEN jobs.alt_company_name IS NOT NULL OR job_files.path IS NOT NULL 
          THEN job_files.path 
          ELSE company_files.path 
        END AS logo_path
      , `applications`.`created_at` as `application_date` 
from `jobs` 
inner join `job_status` on `job_status`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
inner join `recruiters` on `recruiters`.`id` = `jobs`.`recruiter_id`
inner join `companies` on `companies`.`id` = `recruiters`.`company_id` 
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `jobs`.`location_id` 
inner join `location_name` on `location_name`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
inner join `job_language` on `job_language`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
inner join `languages` on `languages`.`id` = `job_language`.`language_id` 
inner join `job_industry` on `job_industry`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join `job_salary` on `job_salary`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join (SELECT fileable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
            FROM files WHERE file_type = "JobLogo" AND fileable_type = "App\\Job"
            GROUP BY fileable_id) AS subquery_one on `subquery_one`.`fileable_id` = `jobs`.`id` 
left join `files` as `job_files` on `job_files`.`fileable_id` = `subquery_one`.`fileable_id` and `job_files`.`created_at` = `subquery_one`.`min_created_at` 
left join (SELECT fileable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
            FROM files WHERE file_type = "CompanyLogo" AND fileable_type = "App\\Company"
            GROUP BY fileable_id) AS subquery_two on `subquery_two`.`fileable_id` = `companies`.`id` 
left join `files` as `company_files` on `company_files`.`fileable_id` = `subquery_two`.`fileable_id` and `company_files`.`created_at` = `subquery_two`.`min_created_at` 
left join `job_shortlist` on `job_shortlist`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` and `job_shortlist`.`jobseeker_id` is NULL 
left join `applications` on `applications`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id` and `applications`.`jobseeker_id` is NULL 
where (`languages`.`id` in ('1') or `languages`.`parent_id` in ('1')) 
and `job_industry`.`industry_id` in ('1') 
and `jobs`.`contract_type_id` in ('3') 
and `jobs`.`contract_hour_id` in ('1') 
and `applications`.`id` is NULL 
and `jobs`.`start_at` <= '2020-03-13 15:06:29' 
and `jobs`.`end_at` >= '2020-03-13 15:06:29' 
and `jobs`.`status_id` = 4 
order by jobs.start_at desc, jobs.id desc limit 4
```

Explain results:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                 | key                                     | key_len | ref                                 | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jobs          | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,jobs_status_id_foreign,jobs_recruiter_id_foreign,jobs_contract_type_id_foreign,jobs_contract_hour_id_foreign,jobs_location_id_foreign | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                |    6 |    16.67 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_language  | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,job_language_language_id_foreign                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | languages     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,languages_parent_id_index                                                                                                             | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.job_language.language_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_industry  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,job_industry_industry_id_foreign                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                                 | 8       | testjobsdb.jobs.id,const            |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jobs          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,jobs_status_id_foreign                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_salary    | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | recruiters    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,recruiters_company_id_foreign                                                                                                         | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.recruiter_id        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | companies     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.recruiters.company_id    |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | status_types  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.status_id           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | locations     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.location_id         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t0            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | testjobsdb.jobs.location_id         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                                                                                                                   | <auto_key1>                             | 5       | testjobsdb.jobs.id                  |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_files     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>    | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key1>                                                                                                                                   | <auto_key1>                             | 5       | testjobsdb.recruiters.company_id    |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | company_files | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | job_shortlist | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,job_shortlist_job_id_unique                                                                                                           | PRIMARY                                 | 8       | const,testjobsdb.jobs.id            |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | applications  | NULL       | eq_ref | applications_job_id_jobseeker_id_unique,applications_jobseeker_id_foreign                                                                     | applications_job_id_jobseeker_id_unique | 8       | testjobsdb.jobs.id,const            |    1 |    25.00 | Using where; Not exists                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t4            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin4_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin4_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin4,const          |    3 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t3            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin3_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin3_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin3,const          |    4 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t2            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin2_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin2_feature_code_index     | 366     | testjobsdb.t0.admin2,const          |   12 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1            | NULL       | ref    | locations_admin1_feature_code_index                                                                                                           | locations_admin1_feature_code_index     | 126     | testjobsdb.t0.admin1,const          |   70 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                              |
|  3 | DERIVED     | files         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |     1.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | files         | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                          | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1712 |     1.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
23 rows in set, 1 warning (0.11 sec)
```

How can I optimize this query. Any advice, hint tips much appreciated.

Comment: What if you put the entire query, without the `id <> 6` condition, in a subquery and apply that condtion in the outer query? _Edit: You'll need to move the ORDER BY and LIMIT to the outer query as well._

Comment: @Uueerdo just tried that and it still takes 7.3 sec which is too slow.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you are LEFT JOINing tables from which you appear to select no columns. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Strawberry I am selecting columns from the left joins inside the case statement

Comment: @adam78 I think he referring to tables like job_salary and job_shortlist.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include DDL and sample data for each of the tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an "explode-implode" pattern -- `JOIN` lots of table together, then eliminate dups (`DISTINCT')`.  Also the `LIMIT` cannot be done until after all the `JOINs`; this could be quite inefficient.

So, try to rewrite it roughly as follows:

```
SELECT ...   -- no DISTINCT
    FROM ( SELECT jobs.id
            FROM jobs
            WHERE ...
            ORDER BY ...
            LIMIT 4 ) AS j
    JOIN ... -- all the other tables, plus `jobs` again
    ORDER BY ...   -- repeated, but no LIMIT repetition
```

`files` needs this composite (and compound) index:

```
INDEX(file_type, fileable_type, fileable_id, created_at)
```

Comment: the files table has a lot of insert/deletes. Will adding an index affect this?

Comment: @adam78 - _Adding_ the index:  takes a bit of time (< 1 second for 1712 rows probably).  _Having_ the index will, I think, significantly speed up the `SELECT` in question.  _Having_ the index will slow down inserts/deleted/updates to `files` by only a small amount.  Overall, it is worth adding the index.

Comment: why is there no distinct in your example? I would need distinct to eliminate dups where I'm searching against a junction table e.g. `and job_industry.industry_id in ('1', '5','6') `? Don't I also need to do joins inside the subquery aswell inorder to add the where conditions?

Comment: @adam78 -  Did you try it, and it showed dups?  Let's see that query formulation; perhaps I can spot where I went wrong.